# How do I search tasks with the Asana API?

Tags: asana

I'd like to search on the name, note, and story.text fields but there's no way to do this. The tasks endpoint requires a project, tag, or workspace+assignee.

The [docs](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tasks) also say "In the future we plan to expand the power of queries to enable filtering by arbitrary fields" but this is not what I want, nor is it implemented yet.

Comment: FYI, this may not be exactly what you're after, but I used this workaround - I tagged each task with a unique tag (e.g. Foo-12n2f9xzl, that I generated by hashing a specific field in the task), and then I queried for all tags with this ID (all = 1 in this case). This allowed me to do a basic "store, retrieve, update" flow even without a formal search API.

Answer (score 4):

We are currently looking into exposing search via the API (no ETA on that yet, it's still in the planning stages) - if it's possible to query for the kind of data you want with the current built-in advanced search, it's likely that API search would cover your use case. Does it look like that would be sufficient?

Comment: Great! I'll respond here when we have something ready to test. :-)

Comment: @agnoster Any update on this? This is a feature I would really love to see.

Comment: Sorry @DanielRasmuson, no update on this - we've got a number of other things that are currently higher priority on the roadmap. But if you send good API developers our way... ;-)

Comment: Very interested in this feature @agnoster! Thanks for your efforts here!